# RelativeLayout inside RelativeLayout is not aligned left completely

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I have a relativelayout inside another relativelayout which has 4 buttons inside. I want to align the inner relativelayout to the left of the parent relativelayout but it doesn't aligned completely, there's an empty space between the left of the inner view with the left of the parent view, here's the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="raw4.kaw.mp2.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background_all" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_btn_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_news"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_news_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_products"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_products_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_main_news"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_aboutus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_aboutus_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_main_products"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_contactus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_contactus_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_main_aboutus"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here's the code in MainActivity.java to reduce the inner layout width to 80% with the alignment rules added:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dpi = metrics.widthPixels;
    int dpiPerc = (int)(dpi * 0.8);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            dpiPerc,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    RelativeLayout main_rl_container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_btn_container);
    main_rl_container.setLayoutParams(params);
```

but this is the result:

[image]

as you can see there's a gap at the left side of the inner layout. thanks for help.

Comment: please remove android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" from parent Relative Layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy paste this code it will solve your problem

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="raw4.kaw.mp2.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background_all" >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/main_btn_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_news"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_news_text"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_products"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_products_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_main_news"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_aboutus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_aboutus_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_main_products"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_main_contactus"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/btn_contactus_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_main_aboutus"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/background_btn"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_btn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

your problem is your parent layout uses `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"` that s why it is not completely to left remove this line and you will get your solution you can copy paste my above code too :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a padding on the parent `RelativeLayout`.

Remove the following line:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Comment: yea this fixes the problem, but Android is everything for was faster :) still a upvote. thanks anyway

Comment: @MiroMarkarian brother take one upvote from me :) and you desrve it

Comment: sorry man I don't know why so showed his answer earlier than yours, this happened few times before as well.. sorry anyway and up voted you

Answer (score 2):

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

It Because of the Dimensions. 
You `do not need to remove these Lines`

But Go to res folder > Values > dimen.xml .
Here By default Specified Some Space allocation for the `activity_horizontal_margin`  change it to `0dp`.

if you delete that line That's Good but, You will face these problem in every XML file you going to Create. So I think this solution is better.

Answer (score -1):

Seams to me because of the padding that are set in root RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="raw4.kaw.mp2.MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background_all" >
```